# Opening a Form2 by clicking a textbox?

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

How do I make so when I click on a textbox, make form2 open?

I understand is something like

```
Form2 f2 = new form2();
f2.show();
```

but its not a button, it's a textbox.

Im currently expressing some values in the textbox, and I want to click the textbox and form 2 to appear, which haves 4 option to change the value into.

```
listBox2.Items.Add(" 1       " + seatArray[0].PrintInfo);
listBox2.Items.Add(" 2       " + seatArray[1].PrintInfo);
listBox2.Items.Add(" 3       " + seatArray[2].PrintInfo);
listBox2.Items.Add(" 4       " + seatArray[3].PrintInfo);
```

---

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string test = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0,2);
            int num = int.Parse(test);
            textBox1.Text = test;//Row
            textBox2.Text = seatArray[num-1].A.ToString();
            textBox7.Text = seatArray[num-1].B.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = seatArray[num-1].C.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = seatArray[num-1].D.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = seatArray[num-1].E.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = seatArray[num-1].F.ToString();

        }
```

---

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
          f.Show(); 


    }
```

when I click and item on my listbox, it summons the form 2, but I need for it to open when I click the textbox itself.

Comment: Can we have some more code for what you have so far. There is not enough context here.

Comment: put that in your textbox's `MouseClick` event handler.

Comment: mouse click event handler?

Answer (score 0):

You need an event handler for the click-event of the textbox:

```
private void NameOfYourTextBox_Click(oject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var secondForm = new form2();
    secondForm.Show();
}
```

Normally you would use

```
secondForm.ShowDialog();
```

to provide a modal form and wrap everything inside an using:

```
private void NameOfYourTextBox_Click(oject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var secondForm = new form2())
    {
        var result = secondForm.ShowDialog();
        // result contains informations on what user did with the form
    }
}
```

because this disposes the form-instance after usage.

So where in this chain is your gap?

Answer (score 0):

place in textbox click event

```
    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }
```